# Django custom login using own model

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django1.4 with PostgreSQL. I am developing an application in which I have two models i.e. Students, Company.

```
class students(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(**option)
    last_name = models.CharField(**option)
    username = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    # Some other attributes for Student models



class company(models.Model):
    compnay_name = models.CharField(**option)
    username = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    #Some other attributes for company models
```

#### My Requirement:

1. Student and Company can create a new profile (provide a sign-up form)
2. Which creating a new profile for Student/Company, username i.e. email id should be unique. i.e. Email id should not exist in Student & Company models.(task completed )
3. Created 2 sign-In form for Student & Company login.

#### Issue:

1. As I am not using or extending User model, I am cannot use django in-built login & authenticate method.
2. How can I write a custom authentication method which should check user credentials in Student/Company username & password. (Have 2 different Sign-in form for Student & Company)

Please help me.

Thanks for reading my query.

#### backend.py

```
class LoginBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, model=None):
        if model == "Student":
            lookup_model = Student
        elif model == "Employer":
            lookup_model = Employer
        try:
            user = lookup_model.objects.get(email=username)
         except Exception, e:
            return None
    return user
```

### views.py

```
def check_auth(request):
    user_object = Student.objects.get(email__iexact = unicode(email))
    if check_password(password, user_object.password):
        print authenticate(username = email, password = password, model = "Student")
        login(request, user_object)
```

### settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("proj.app.backends.LoginBackend",)

### Error

**AttributeError at /xxx/login/**

**'Student' object has no attribute 'backend'**

Comment: Why can you not use the django user authentication system? have you looked at a third party system e.g. [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) module?

Comment: Thats nice.
But already my client provided me DB schema, in which Student & Company model uses "usernmae" & "password" field which cant be changed.

Comment: I highly recommended you to try and change the DB schema so that you will use the User object for the Auth and profile for extending it. I believe it will be the right thing to develope a convertor from the old DB schema to your new one.

Answer (score 7):

Write a custom authentication backend. Read this:

- [Writing an authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend)
- [Handling authorization in custom backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends)
- [settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)

[update]

By writing and registering a custom authentication backend, you just have to use the standard Django authentication patterns. Looking at your sample code, I'm under the impression that you have understood it differently.

Since email is your unique key, I suggest using email for the login key, first check the login/password against Student, and if it fails, check against Company.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class JayapalsBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
         try:
             o = Student.objects.get(email=username, password=password)
         except Student.DoesNotExist:
             try:
                 o = Company.objects.get(email=username, password=password)
             except Company.DoesNotExist:
                 return None
         return User.objects.get(email=o.email)
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then just use standard Django decorators:

```
@login_required
def some_private_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: When I wrote custom auth backend, I got error " 'Student' object has no attribute 'backend'"

Comment: I have custom backends for authenticating against AD, LDAP, POP3, against Sugar CRM and other external applications, so I know for sure that it works as documented. If you have something done, update your question with code samples and what are you getting wrong.

Comment: same error when I use,
    `authenticate(username = email, password = password)`
     `login(request, user_object)`

Comment: @jayapald: your code does not resemble the recommended away to deal with authentication in Django. Just write code like you would if you where using pure Django authentication - use the builtin login view, authenticatnion/authorization decorators. Please read the documentation and follow the examples.

Comment: @jayapald : I guess u r not using the function get_user(self, user_id) in the JaypalBackend class. Make sure that particular function is present.